# A simple question related to the Stolz–Cesàro theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

Let $(a_n)_{\,n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, and define $b_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Suppose that consecutive elements converge:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1.$$
Then, intuitively, it seems plausible that $a_n$ would converge to its corresponding mean $b_n$:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1.$$
Is this limit correct?  If so, how can it be shown?  If not, is there a straightforward counterexample?

---

This problem (which is my own construction) seems closely related to the Stolz–Cesàro theorem, but my attempts to adapt the proof of that theorem have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you try $a_n=1/n$? Or $a_n=n$?

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Much simpler than expected.  I overcommitted to the proof.  (In my application, the $a_n$ are probably $\Theta(1)$, but this can't be assumed, so these counterexamples stand.)

Comment: Sometimes, the obvious escapes us and we acquire invalid assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it because the result is not true.  Consider $a_n = n$, then $a_{n + 1}/a_n = 1 + 1/n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, while
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{n}{\frac{1}{2n}n(n + 1)} \to 2
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.